# Android/Iphone support for the "data-" attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I´m developing an app for Android/Iphones

I´m using JQuery Mobile and PhoneGap.

I need to store some data in a list of links so i was thinking of using this:

And it seems to work on my phone (Android 2.3.3) but when seeing this list:
http://html5test.com/compare/feature/elements-dataset.html (scroll down to Android phones)

it seems that ALOT of phones webbrowsers doesn't support the "data" attribute feature. Is that really correct? Why does it work on my Android 2.3.3 phone when in the link above it says it doesn't.

Comment: What makes you think that they don't support `data`? AFAIK all mobile (webkit & Opera) browsers offer support: http://caniuse.com/dataset

Comment: I'm not sure, but even if the browsers officially not support this `data-*` attribute, it should work. The new special behavior of the `data-` prefix is, that it has no impact to the layout. But the old browsers don't know this attribute for layout rendering either, so: should be no problem and should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the html5test.com site is in error or it has some special meaning for “Embedding custom non-visible data”.

The usual reference caniuse.com says that `data-` attributes as such are supported by all browsers, but there are differences in the ways they can be accessed:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset